# Anchoring a new Lua thread

Tags: c, lua

From the documentation, I understand that a new thread created, must be 
properly **anchored** before use.
To do that, I want to keep a reference to the new thread in the *registry*, 
(`Table[thread-addr] =  thread`) for that, I am doing this:

```
lua_State *L = NULL;
lua_State *L1 = NULL;
int tref = LUA_NOREF;

L = luaL_newstate(); // main lua thread/state

// create a table in registry: Table[thr-addr] = Thread
lua_newtable(L);
tref = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
lua_pop(L, 1); 

L1 = lua_newthread(L);
// Anchor it
lua_rawgeti(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, tref);
lua_pushnumber(L, (ptrdiff_t) L1);
lua_pushlightuserdata(L, L1);
lua_settable(L, -3);
```

Once I am done with the thread, I plan to set the `Table[thread-addr] = nil`
Is this sufficient ? or I should also set a meta-table to it, with weak keys/values ?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure: You do know that Lua - without special modules - does not support true multithreading, but only coroutines?

Comment: @dualed, yes, I am aware of it.

Comment: `L1 = lua_newthread(L)` already pushes the new thread onto L's stack.

Comment: Just curious but why do you have a `lua_pop` below `luaL_ref`? The documentation for `luaL_ref` claims it pops whatever was on the stack, so technically this should not be needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Once I am done with the thread, I plan to set the `Table[thread-addr] = nil` Is this sufficient? or I should also set a meta-table to it, with weak keys/values?

A weak table is used if you don't want objects it references to count as real 'strong' references. So Lua is allowed to `GC` an object if there are no other references to it even if the weak table still refers to that object.

From the use case you described, making `Table` weak probably isn't appropriate here since Lua might collect that coroutine object before you have a chance to use it.

Also your example code here:

```
L1 = lua_newthread(L);
// Anchor it
lua_rawgeti(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, tref);
lua_pushnumber(L, (ptrdiff_t) L1);
lua_pushlightuserdata(L, L1);
lua_settable(L, -3);
```

the `lua_pushlightuserdata` function is meant for C pointers. The coroutine object lifetime won't get managed by Lua correctly if you tell it to treat the coroutine object like a C data pointer. For this you probably meant to use `lua_pushthread` instead.

Comment: Oh ya! I should have used `lua_pushthread`! ( `lua_pushthread` pushes on its own stack, so I need to replace `lua_pushlightuserdata` in the above code snippet with: `lua_pushthread(L1); lua_xmove(L1, L, 1);` - is that correct?. Thanks.

Comment: Actually `lua_pushvalue(L, -3);` in place of `lua_pushlightuserdata`.